# How to avoid "skipped by smartStep" in visual studio code

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have a huge server application (nodeJs) with many files and functions. I try to debug it via Visual Studio Code. I put break point to some function which I assume will be called in proper time and run debug.
But debugger stopped in some "random" place of node modules files and say - "Skipped by smartStep". What is it? I don't want to have this unexpected behaviour. If my function isn't call, I just want that the program goes through the chain and skipped it.
How to turn off "smart step" and what of is this feature about?

Comment: Are you working with typescript ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove node_modules works for me. I'm on ( Ubuntu + VSCode 1.72.0 + Typescrypt with Jest)

I don't know the root cause

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to remove "--inspect-brk=18971" in my "runtimeArgs" in the launch.json file for Vscode.

I thought this was needed to hit breakpoints, but apparently in my case it's not, as I'm able to hit other breakpoints without the annoying smart step breakpoints that I did not set myself.

If that doesn't work, also look into "debug.javascript.autoAttachFilter" in VScode settings.json. Not sure what it does but seems related.

Answer (score 0):

The Smart Step feature is about skipping uninteresting (generated boiler-plate) code.

From [Visual Studio Codes Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_smart-stepping)

> ### Smart stepping
>
> With the `smartStep attribute set to true in a launch configuration, VS Code will automatically skip 'uninteresting code' when stepping through code in the debugger. 'Uninteresting code' is code that is generated by a transpiling process but is not covered by a source map so it does not map back to the original source. This code gets in your way when stepping through source code in the debugger because it makes the debugger switch between the original source code and generated code that you are not interested in. **smartStep will automatically step through code not covered by a source map** until it reaches a location that is covered by a source map again.
>
> Smart stepping is especially useful for cases like async/await downcompilation in TypeScript, where the compiler injects helper code that is not covered by a source map.
>
> **The smartStep feature only applies to JavaScript code that was generated from source and therefore has a source map. For JavaScript without sources, the smart stepping option has no effect.**

### How to Disable `smartStep`

To disable it, your Launch Configuration must include `smartStep: false`:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/your/program.js",
            "skipFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.js",
                "<node_internals>/**/*.js"
            ],
            "smartStep": false // << this is where the magic happens
        },
    ]
}
```

### A Word of Caution

If the `smartStep` function ignores your code, this means something is wrong with your source maps.

Double-Check your Babel configuration if it includes something like [`sourceMaps: true`](https://babeljs.io/docs/options#sourcemaps).

(Under certain obscure circumstances I had no source maps for some TypeScript files in my Jest tests. I gave up trying to fix it, and hope for some future release to fix it. (With [`retainLines: true`](https://babeljs.io/docs/options#retainlines) you can step through broken source/maps a little more comfortable.))

Answer (score -3):

You can simply uncheck the breakpoint in the "skipped by smartStep" file.

Comment: That assumes there is a breakpoint in the "skipped by smartStep" file to uncheck - in my case there isn't.